# How to trace Windows Workflow 4 in a rehosted WF Designer?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I need to show the current state of a workflow. For that purpose I have developed a programm which is rehosting the Workflow Designer and show my workflow. Ok - that was the easy part.

Next, I need to prevent any editing in the workflow. I found the following solution for that, which work perfect:

```
  var readOnlyState = WorkflowDesigner.Context.Items.GetValue<ReadOnlyState>();
  if (readOnlyState != null)
      readOnlyState.IsReadOnly = true;
```

But how do I visually trace my workflow?  And I also need to enrich/augment all activities with additional meta information (like their current status or a count).

Has anyone an idea how I could insert an overlay or any other kind of visual element to show additional information for an activity?

Thanks

-Goerge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sample VisualWorkflowTrackingWithStepService from Kushal Shah that should help you get started. Yoi can find the sample [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kushals/archive/2009/12/29/visualworkflowtrackingwithstepservice.aspx).

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kushals/archive/2010/01/04/base-designer-with-additional-adornments.aspx) is another of Kushal's blog post you might want to take a look at,